# Rails leaflet map geosearch stopped working after precompiling assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, leaflet

I'm using meijer's geosearch in a leaflet map. It was working fine but I've suddenly broken it and I don't know how. The maps still appears, but the search box doen't appear in the map. The code that breaks the app is (leaflet_map.js):

```
new L.Control.GeoSearch({
  provider: new L.GeoSearch.Provider.OpenStreetMap(),
  showMarker: false,
  position: 'topright',
  retainZoomLevel: false
}).addTo(map);
```

I don't think it can find the geosearch js or css files, even though I've clearly included them in application.html.erb:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "leaflet.css" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "leaflet.js" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "l.geosearch.css" %> 
<%= javascript_include_tag "l.control.geosearch.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "l.geosearch.provider.openstreetmap.js" %>
```

I think the turning point might have been when I typed `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` at the command line (I also did `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`). Why would that break geosearch? 
I have deleted my public/assets folder, but that didn't make any difference.

Also, the console doesn't show any complaints about broken geosearch.js files or not finding them. I am, as usual, baffled.

js console:

```
Uncaught Error: Map container not found.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Provider' of undefined
Mixed Content: The page at 'xxxx' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/13/7424/5131.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

view:

```
<div id="map-leaflet"></div>
<%= javascript_include_tag "easy-button" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "leaflet_map" %>
```

leaflet_map.js

```
map = L.map('map-leaflet', {center: [10.0, 10.0], zoom: 16} );
map.options.maxZoom = 22;
L.tileLayer(
  'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
  maxZoom: 22
}).addTo(map);

// add location search box
new L.Control.GeoSearch({
  provider: new L.GeoSearch.Provider.OpenStreetMap(),
  showMarker: false,
  position: 'topright',
  retainZoomLevel: false
}).addTo(map);
```

Demo site [here](https://websmash.herokuapp.com)

Comment: can you show us the errors in your js console?and your view source?

Comment: I think we need to see your `leaflet_map` source as well.

Comment: Any chance of you showing us this on a demo site?

Comment: Certainly. Have a look [here](https://websmash.herokuapp.com).

Answer (score 1):

Your `leaflet-map` init code is being included twice, once inside [`<script src="/assets/leaflet_map-8e1007491534b1245e2ccc867a845d14e60679a58ca180c5e9cbef68530aa571.js"></script>`](https://websmash.herokuapp.com/assets/leaflet_map-8e1007491534b1245e2ccc867a845d14e60679a58ca180c5e9cbef68530aa571.js)and once from [application.js](https://websmash.herokuapp.com/assets/application-4e8cab3b31acf17a44535885213c8ce326ac2896c15d0b4254965484fbd42a44.js). Drop the `leaflet-map` asset reference underneath your map div to begin working through these problems.

Comment: Thank you, the double-inclusion was causing the trouble. However, I solved the problem by removing the line `//= require_tree .` from application.js. Removing the `leaflet-map` reference immediately after the map div declaration broke it. Leaflet requires its code to be called after the map div delcaration (see [here](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html)). Not being able to use `//= require_tree .` is irritating, now I have to manually include all js files. But at least it works!

Comment: Well yes, leaflet can only run its init code if the div element you want to be working with exists.Some people choose to run their init code inside a $(document).ready to avoid having to deal with that.